# How to find volume charge density from Electric field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, gauss-law

[image]

What will be the volume charge density for this field...I tried using the differential form of gauss law but the r^2 term is canceling and I am having problem getting the delta function..

Comment: Please note that this site is not a place to obtain solutions to worked problems. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/25301) and [this Meta post for "check my work problems"](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/25301).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental equation here is
$$
\vec\nabla\cdot\left(\frac{\hat r}{r^2}\right)=4\pi\delta^3(\vec r).
$$
This can be proven through Fourier analysis, but you can intuitively understand that this works in the case of a single charge $q$: take the field of a single charge at the origin
$$
\vec E=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q}{r^2}\hat r.
$$
We know that this field is sourced by a point charge at the origin: this is consistent with our previous equation, as
$$
\vec\nabla\cdot\vec E=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\vec\nabla\cdot\left(\frac {\hat r}{r^2}\right)=\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}q\delta^3(\vec r).
$$
Also, by direct computation, you have
$$
\vec \nabla r=\frac{\vec r}{r}=\hat r.
$$

Now that you have those rules, you can simply calculate the divergence of your electric field.
$$
\vec \nabla\cdot \vec E=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\vec\nabla\cdot\left(\frac{e^{-br}\hat r}{r^2}\right)=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\vec \nabla e^{-br} \cdot\frac{\hat r}{r^2}+e^{-br}\vec\nabla\cdot\left(\frac{\hat r}{r^2}\right)\right).
$$
Applying the rules that we have found, we get
$$
\vec\nabla\cdot\vec E=\frac{q}{\epsilon_0}\left(\delta^3(\vec r)-\frac{b}{4\pi r^2}\right)e^{-br},
$$
as expected.